# How to connect facebook, gmail, twitter account when logged in with same email id?

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

I am implementing sign-in screen for my app, and trying to figure out how can I connect facebook, gmail and twitter for same email id in my parse server.Any idea?

Comment: check this library https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to link the returned id from facebook API, twitter API, Gmail API and save its return id to your currently/new signed in user.

e.g.

```
Customer Table:

customer_id facebook_id google_id twitter_id email
 1          12313323    11231231  123123123  foo@bar.com
```

So whenever someone logined from the three api it always returns to a specific customer used to login.